# Android URL scheme doen't open my app on click in app which has build-in browser

Tags: android, url, url-scheme

I use URL scheme to open my app on the specific page if user clicks url from email or sms, for example, https://dev.example.com/z/abcd .

I've added an intent filter to manifest file and it works properly if link is clicked in Gmail app. But it doesn't work if the link was clicked in app which has build-in browser (for example, Telegram or Samsung default messaging app) webpage is just opened inside the app...
Is it possible to force my app open in all the apps where url was clicked?

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="dev.example.com" android:pathPattern="/z/.*" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="dev.example.com" android:pathPattern="/z/.*" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```